# Django or Firebase for a project with few users

Tags: django, firebase, flutter, rest, backend

I am a beginner and looking forward to start freelancing with flutter.
And I am wondering whether or not is **Firebase** better than **Django** for small projects that doesn't require alot of users concerning the **price**
as firebase is alot easier than django

Comment: [Why doesn't Stack Overflow allow discussable questions or questions that requires opinions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252854/why-doesnt-stack-overflow-allow-discussable-questions-or-questions-that-require)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django is a web framework and Firebase is a backend as a service. They are different things. So if you want to write the entire backend and host it somewhere yourself use Django.  If you don't want to worry about writing a backend use firebase.